# Calculate the genus of $C=\{[X,Y,Z] \in \mathbb P^2\mathbb C \mid X^5 + Y^5 + Z^5=0\}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemannian-geometry, algebraic-curves

> **Problem:** Let $X,Y,Z$ be homogeneous coordinates in $\mathbb P^2\mathbb C$ and
>
> $$C=\{[X,Y,Z] \in \mathbb P^2\mathbb C \mid X^5 + Y^5 + Z^5=0\}.$$
>
> Calculate the genus of $C$ and find a base for $\Omega^1(C)$.

**Thoughts:** $C$ is smooth, thus $g=(5-1)(5-2)/2=6$. In the chart $Z \not=0$ the equation becomes $x^5 + y^5 + 1 =0$ and thus $$\frac {dx}{y^4}=\frac {-dy}{x^4}$$
is a holomorphic $1$-form.

Thanks!

Comment: If you think the genus is $6$, then the dimension of the space of $1$-forms is $6$, so you're looking for six elements, not one.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm looking for holomorphic forms only. I don't know if it is meant to be a base over $\mathbb R$ or whatever. The solution here is $\frac {x^iy^jdx}{y^4}$ with $i+j \leq 2$ so I guess there are 9 forms. Thanks!

Comment: Six,  you surely mean!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez YES! I just noticed I did a mistake in the computation. Anyway why are they 6, and why of that kind? There is no further explanation next to the solution! Thanks!

Comment: The genus is precisely the number of holomorphic differential forms.

Comment: "There is no further explanation next to the solution!" What is the source (book/notes) you are using? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Dim_{\mathbb C} \Omega^1(C)= g$ thanks to [Hodge Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_theory).

A base is given by $\frac{\phi(x,y)dx}{F_y}$ with $\phi(x,y)$ every polynomial of degree at most $d-3=5-3=2$.